# Cannot match route index

Tags: angularjs, angular

Using the last version of angular 2 router (3.0.0-rc.1) and angular 2 (RC5). My router has the following routes:

```
{ path: 'transport', redirectTo: 'transport/entity-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'transport/entity-list', component: EntityListComponent },
{ path: 'transport/cover-list', component: CoverListComponent },
{ path: 'transport/invoice-list', component: InvoiceListComponent },
{ path: 'transport/damage-list', component: DamageListComponent }
```

My server (ExpressJS) has the pug library and renders my index as follow:

```
res.render('index');
```

I also have the base tag in my index.pug

```
head
    base(href="/")
```

In `MyComponent` I also import the `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES`

When I load the index, everything renders but I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'index'
```

From what I understand, angular's router is trying to route index but doesn't see it in the path. So I've tried to add `index` as a path but get:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MyComponent'
```

I have two questions:

1. What am I doing wrong and how can I get rid of this error?
2. How can I get index load `transport/entity-list` from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing index path on your routing, so what you did is correct.

For your other issue:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MyComponent'
```

Do you have this defined on your template?

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Actually yes, but in my app.component.js which is loaded through systemJS (as recommended in angular 2 documentation)

Comment: I realized I was delaying the router-outlet creation to load my app data! Thanks for pointing that

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `pathMatch: 'full'` to your instead of `useAsDefault`

```
{ path: 'transport', redirectTo: 'transport/entity-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help...I changed the `pathMatch` in the question!

Comment: It seems that the router tries to route `/index`! It's weird because /index has the `base(href="/")` and even if I add the `/index` path it doesn't "find" it